# Python catch text inside {}

Tags: python, regex

I need to catch all the text inside the {} parenthesis in python

this is an example

```
{NOKIA}_B {Lumia 640 XL}_M {LTE}_O {8GB}_S
```

I need to catch the contain of the {} parenthesis for example Nokia and also the tag that the _* part. 
SO for example in {NOKIA}_B I need to extract both Nokia and the B tag.
I tried without success with this regex that unfortunately doesn't work for multi tokens word

```
{\w{1,}}_(B|M|S|C|O)
```

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't work"*? Do you know what characters `\w` matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of capture groups and `findall` to extract all needed properties

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "{NOKIA}_B {Lumia 640 XL}_M {LTE}_O {8GB}_S"
>>> matches = re.findall(r"\{([0-9a-zA-Z ]*)\}", s)
>>> print matches
['NOKIA', 'Lumia 640 XL', 'LTE', '8GB']
```